# Angular-JS, modal doesn't close as intended

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS 1.3.7 with Angular-ui-bootstrap 0.14.3

I have a problem with fairly simple code (I simplified it a lot and yet problem still persists), yet I couldn't see the source of problem. I create a modal that supposed to dismiss when I click outside of the modal

Here my html code:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
    <div>
        <button ng-click="testModal()"> test </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

here my js code:

```
angular.module('testModule', [])
    .controller('TestController', TestController)
    .controller('TestModalController', TestModalController)

function TestController($scope, $modal){
    $scope.testModal = function(){
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl : '...blabla/test.html',
            controller : 'TestModalController',
            resolve : {}
        });
    }
}

function TestModalController(){
    dummy = function(){
        var hello = "hello";
    }
}
```

and here my test.html called from templateUrl of the modal:

```
<button ng-click="dummy()">DUMMY</button>
```

Now as for the definition of problem I will tell you about cases

I click "test" button and open the modal.

**Case 1**: I just press ESC key and the modal closes. All OK.

**Case 2**: I just click Dummy button and nothing happens. All OK.

**Case 3**: I just click outside of modal and nothing happens. Not okay, it should have closed the modal.

**Case 4**: I just click outside of modal and nothing happens, then I click on Dummy button and modal closes.

**Case 5**: I just click outside of modal and nothing happens, then I press ESC again nothing happens, finally when i click Dummy button modal closes.

**-** I also tried adding "**backdrop: true**" , it didn't change anything. (**backdrop: 'static'** did what it should.)

**-** Also changed all "**modal**" words to "**uibModal**" and nothing changed regarding the problem.

**-** I don't get any kind of error message in console.

Comment: have u injected bootstap.js and css ??

Comment: yes they are included